# DBIx::Class query fails, yet dump from DBIC_TRACE works

Tags: perl, orm, dbix-class

I cannot rewrite the current DB schema right now BTW, but that's beside the point to the issue I've hit, so please ignore the table structure :D

I'm running this DB query:

```
my $rs = $dbx->resultset('Result')->search(
           {
             'result_hnd'         => 16078055,
             'seasons.outdoor'    => 'venue.outdoors',
             'seasons.start_date' => { '<=' => 'meet.date_end'   },
             'seasons.end_date'   => { '>=' => 'meet.date_begin' },
           },
           {
             'join' => [
               {
                 'team' => {
                   'league_teams' => {
                     'league' => 'seasons',
                   },
                 },
               },
               {
                 'meet' => 'venue'
               },
             ],
             '+select' => ['seasons.season_hnd','seasons.name','seasons.start_date','seasons.end_date','meet.date_begin','meet.date_end'],
             '+as'     => ['season_hnd','season_name','s_start','s_end','m_start','m_end'],
             columns   => ['result_hnd'],
             group_by  => ['seasons.season_hnd'],
           }
         );
```

When I run this, I get no results. With DBIC_TRACE on, I see the generated SQL as:

```
SELECT me.result_hnd, seasons.season_hnd, seasons.name, seasons.start_date, seasons.end_date, meet.date_begin, meet.date_end FROM track.result me JOIN track.team team ON team.team_hnd = me.team_hnd LEFT JOIN track.league_team league_teams ON league_teams.team_hnd = team.team_hnd LEFT JOIN track.league league ON league.league_hnd = league_teams.league_hnd LEFT JOIN track.season seasons ON seasons.league_hnd = league.league_hnd OR seasons.league_hnd = league.parent_league_hnd JOIN track.meet meet ON meet.meet_hnd = me.meet_hnd JOIN track.venue venue ON venue.venue_hnd = meet.venue_hnd WHERE ( ( result_hnd = ? AND seasons.end_date >= ? AND seasons.outdoor = ? AND seasons.start_date <= ? ) ) GROUP BY seasons.season_hnd: '16078055', 'meet.date_begin', 'venue.outdoors', 'meet.date_end'
```

When I copy and paste this statement into my MYSQL client (and interpolate the placeholders), like this:

```
SELECT me.result_hnd, seasons.season_hnd, seasons.name, seasons.start_date, seasons.end_date, meet.date_begin, meet.date_end 
  FROM track.result me 
      JOIN track.team team ON team.team_hnd = me.team_hnd 
      LEFT JOIN track.league_team league_teams ON league_teams.team_hnd = team.team_hnd 
      LEFT JOIN track.league league ON league.league_hnd = league_teams.league_hnd 
      LEFT JOIN track.season seasons ON seasons.league_hnd = league.league_hnd OR seasons.league_hnd = league.parent_league_hnd 
      JOIN track.meet meet ON meet.meet_hnd = me.meet_hnd 
      JOIN track.venue venue ON venue.venue_hnd = meet.venue_hnd 
WHERE ( ( result_hnd = 16078055 AND seasons.end_date >= meet.date_begin AND seasons.outdoor = venue.outdoors AND seasons.start_date <= meet.date_end ) ) 
  GROUP BY season_hnd;
```

I get the exact result I expect (7 records).

This is really bizarre. To all intents and purposes, isn't that exactly the same query? Am I missing something in my debugging? Or is something else happening at the DBIx::Class::ResultSet layer that isn't being dumped?

Answer (score 4):

To tell SQL::Abstract that the value on the right is actually an identifier, you can do the following (as outlined in the [docs](https://metacpan.org/module/SQL%3a%3aAbstract#ident)):

```
   {
     'result_hnd'         => 16078055,
     'seasons.outdoor'    => { -ident => 'venue.outdoors' },
     'seasons.start_date' => { '<=' => { -ident => 'meet.date_end' }   },
     'seasons.end_date'   => { '>=' => { -ident => 'meet.date_begin' } },
   },
```

Comment: @cliveholloway - mind accepting the answer if was the solution?

Answer (score 1):

> To all intents and purposes, isn't that exactly the same query?

(*For* all intents and purposes, ...)

No. In the log, you have something equivalent to

```
result_hnd = '16078055'
AND seasons.end_date >= 'meet.date_begin'
AND seasons.outdoor = 'venue.outdoors'
AND seasons.start_date <= 'meet.date_end'
```

or maybe

```
result_hnd = 16078055
AND seasons.end_date >= 'meet.date_begin'
AND seasons.outdoor = 'venue.outdoors'
AND seasons.start_date <= 'meet.date_end'
```

In your attempt, you used

```
result_hnd = 16078055
AND seasons.end_date >= meet.date_begin
AND seasons.outdoor = venue.outdoors
AND seasons.start_date <= meet.date_end
```

Sorry, I don't have the solution for you.

Comment: But DBIx interpolates the table.field attributes in the query as intended. Is that not the correct ssyntax in the query part of the search?

Comment: Ignore above comment - it only does that in the relationship definitions, not queries.